# Hyperlink url contains localhost and port number

Tags: asp.net, html

I am creating a searching website using ASP.NET .On my one page I show URL of results.When I click on URL a new link is open but the URL path for the new link in the browser include loalhost:portnumbet.I do not want this in my URL.

For eg.

```
    <a href = "https://www.google.com"> result </a>
```

so on clicking result I go to browser where the URL is "https://localhost:8080//www.google.com"
why this localhost:8080 includes in the URL.

Thanks

Comment: What does the code look like for the links you're using? If you don't show more of your code, I'm afraid all we'll be doing is guessing. ;)  Use this [edit] link to add more info. Good luck! :)

Comment: no one can help u without analyze ur code...please give some sample code for analyzing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are redirecting to the URL, you will not be adding any protocol information, so it will default to the current website/protocol.

For example;

```
Response.Redirect("www.google.com")
```

is not the same as;

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com")
```

You need to add the `fully qualified` URL, otherwise it will believe it to be`relative` to the current website, therefore add the `http(s)://` to the redirect.